# How does geoprocessing results window store tasks?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, results-window

Yesterday I was working in a single mxd all day, performing dozens of calculations and other analysis using multiple tools. A lot of it was trial and error, so when I found the correct combination I would label it as such in the `Results` window before documenting it in OneNote.

[image: Geoprocessing results]

I opened and closed that mxd multiple times, and was able to rerun those tools I had labelled, as expected. When I opened that mxd this morning at work, I found that the tools I had renamed had been reset to their default names - as a result, I've had to trawl through each result until I found the ones I wanted.

What I would like to know is, seeing as the processed tasks persist between sessions as it stored inside the mxd, so even if I open it on a different computer the results are still there, why does it "forget" that I renamed some of them?

Comment: I would doubt if it actually allows you to do that i.e rename a session and persist the change. It could very well be by design...as this is not the right place to save your work in progress.

Comment: It is not possible to rename the session, I am referring to if you right click the result in the window, it gives you the option to `Rename` that particular result. If this does not persist between sessions, then what is the point of having that option there?

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know you could rename these.  And I right click on these all the time.  How did I miss that?

Comment: Yup...that does seem like a goof-up.

Comment: I only saw this yesterday morning as well :)

Comment: I like to delete the ones that didn't work or gave me unexpected results, thereby decluttering the results window quite nicely for future referencing.

Comment: Right click > `Save As` result file... why?

Comment: Results can be dragged and dropped between mxds and will be stored in the `Shared` session node.

Comment: This seems to be saved with the MXD and as @matt wilke noted in his [Answer to another question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138789/improving-arcgis-results-saving-and-manipulating/176121#176121) you can't drag from the current session to a shared session but must drag from previous sessions. -- In the documentation it seems the Log File XML and the Results are *not* identical -> ["The information contained in the log file is **essentially the same** as that found in the Results window."](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/executing-tools/history-log-files.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug to me because [Using the Results window](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002100000013000000) says that Rename on the Result shortcut menu ...

> Renames the result. The default name is the tool name followed by the
> time and date.

I would recommend reporting it but in the meantime I would suggest that Copy As Python Snippet might be an alternative and perhaps better way to record results and re-run them later.

---

As [commented by @mattwilkie](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48943/how-does-the-geoprocessing-results-window-store-the-tasks/48945?noredirect=1#comment202845_48945):

> ... the bug is still present in 10.3. I logged it with Esri,
> *BUG-000082214 - [Renaming a result in the Results window is not maintained when an MXD is closed and reopened.]*.

As [commented by @user23715](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48943/how-does-the-geoprocessing-results-window-store-the-tasks/48945?noredirect=1#comment635888_48945):

> Bug is **still** present in ArcMap 10.8.1 and listed as "In Product Plan"

[BUG-000082214](https://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/QlVHLTAwMDA4MjIxNA==) being in the Product Plan suggests that it has been assigned to a programmer to work on for the next release.  If that work is successful and passes Beta testing then I would expect that it will appear in the next release.

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround for persistent rename:

1. Rename a process
2. Drag to “Shared”
3. Save mxd

In the Shared container the process retains the tool name, e.g. "Append", but automatically get's a new parent with the wanted label.

Think ahead because once in Shared it can't be renamed again.

[image: Step one, rename the Session result]

After close and re-open:

[image: Step 4: after re-open mxd]

Comment: Related: Using shared results for process step documentation http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/176121/108