# Saving Result File from command line ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, results-window

What do I need to do in order to get a custom arcpy script to save an execution run into the [Results window](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/executing-tools/using-the-results-window.htm), and/or just straight to an `.rlt` file directly?

The script is run from the command line and isn't in a toolbox.

Motivation: I use results as documentation, to see what has been done in a particular project, and to recreate particular steps dynamically at will, confident that I will get the same outcome.  Significant steps are saved as .rlt for future reference and re-use in other projects. I want to capture my non-toolbox scripts as well as model scripts in this manner as well as stock tools.

[image: Result window showing place where script run would be]

Comment: Looks like ArcPy gp tools return a result object you can save using the saveToFile method. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z00000046000000

Comment: @EokN. answer is correct to save a result to a file. But the only way to get a result is to have it run as a tool. You wont/cant see a py script execution in the results window. You could wrap your script as a script tool and execute it from inside ArcGIS. That would give you a result

Comment: @EokN. True, although that would have to be done for each GP tool that is called within the script, creating separate files for each. Back to the question: Is there a reason you don't want to build your scripts into toolboxes? You wouldn't necessarily have to change the script, in fact you could write a generic toolbox to run a script with given parameters....that would 'document' that you ran it, etc.

Comment: @EvilGenius adding a script to a toolbox tedious, so I tend to avoid it unless it's something that warrants the extra work. Consequently only about a 3rd of the scripts I use end up being recorded. :-/    The idea of a generic "run this" tool is interesting. I might explore that.

Comment: this is a sub case of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138789/improving-arcgis-results-saving-and-manipulating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @KHibma:

> the only way to get a result is to have it run as a tool. You
>   wont/cant see a py script execution in the results window. You could
>   wrap your script as a script tool and execute it from inside ArcGIS.
>   That would give you a result